# Delete Row of only visible cells

Tags: excel, vba, visible

I have a macro that compiles data from another worksheet and then manipulates said data.  My first step is filtering by blanks and deleting all of the rows that appear.  I thought I wrote the code correctly but I'm not apparently not, because each time I get a **Run-time error '1004': Application-define or object-defined error**
I don't see anything wrong with my variables, the column I'm filtering by is column D.

If you can see anything in my code that would help I'd love to know.  Thank you!

```
Sub X50()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, macro As Worksheet, Pscrub As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim mlastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("X50 - All")
lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count), Count:=2
    Sheets(3).Select
    Sheets(3).Name = "Pre Scrub"
    Sheets(4).Select
    Sheets(4).Name = "Macro"

Set Pscrub = wb.Sheets("Pre Scrub")
Set macro = wb.Sheets("Macro")
mlastRow = macro.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("AM6:AM" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=macro.Range("A1")
ws.Range("AL6:AL" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=macro.Range("B1")
ws.Range("F6:F" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=macro.Range("C1")
ws.Range("E6:E" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=macro.Range("D1")
ws.Range("G6:G" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=macro.Range("E1")
ws.Range("K6:K" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=macro.Range("F1")

macro.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=(""), _
         Operator:=xlFilterValues
macro.Range("D2:D" & mlastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
macro.AutoFilterMode = False

wsPrescrub.Range("$A$1:$F$" & mlastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) _
        , Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: What line produces the error?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to look at your last line of code, and change the sheet object to either ws or Pscrub ?
Not sure which object wsPrescrub is and where it is declared.

Comment: btw, you can filter for blanks and delete for xlCellTypeVisible or forget the filter and delete for xlCellTypeBlanks; there is no need to do both.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Do you have a screenshot of your data?

Comment: The picture imbedding isn't working for me.  It's the line macro.Range("D2:D" & mlastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
  I have no idea why it's not working.